# Angular2: Can't inject service into service

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection

So here is my code, I do believe you can understand what I'm trying to accomplish with no additional explanations.

```
@Injectable()
export class Dispatcher {
}

@Injectable()
export class TodoStore {

    constructor(@Inject(Dispatcher) private dispatcher:Dispatcher){ 

    }
}

@Component({
    ...
      providers:[TodoStore,Dispatcher]
}
export class MyComponent{
    costructor(@Inject(TodoStore) private store:TodoStore) {}
}
```

I'm getting `Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TodoStore: (?).` Any ideas, please

Comment: Do you need to write `@Inject(Dispatcher) private dispatcher: Dispatcher`? Wouldn't it be sufficient to just use `private dispatcher: Dispatcher` and `private store: TodoStore` in your constructors?

Comment: yeah, I was trying this `private store: TodoStore` and it works as well, but not resolving current issue

Comment: @Inject and other decorators duplicate each other, there's no need to use them both. The code above should work. Something is behind the scenes that you didn't show. A fiddle/plunk that can replicate the issue is needed.

Comment: I created a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/aSZvpgw6SFMBFWjZPWTR?p=preview) to try your code and it works like a charm...

Comment: Hm, which version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

This should work, and it works for me. It is not possible to say why it doesn't work in your case,  without the complete code and setup.

Two comments: constructor was misspelled, and @Inject(...) is unneeded.